# Best way for a tabled data structure with named columns of doubles

Tags: c#, data-structures, thread-safety, c#-2.0

I'm searching for a data structure like this:

```
position      whoCares    bla           ...
200.001890     -0.00110    -0.100000
199.997990     0.000790    -2.200000
199.952110     0.026330    -28.900000
199.780060     0.116370    -60.400000
199.321650     0.349330    -154.200000
198.242900     0.901430    -248.700000
196.447890     1.816030    -289.200000
...            ...         ...
```

The table can grow in both dimensions by adding tags or adding new data to a column. Data sizes vary from 3-20 columns and 100-10000 doubles per column.

This should be defined as one data set as one class instance.
The data access should look like this:

```
double[] Get(string tag)             // data.Get("position")
double Get(string tag, int index)    // data.Get("position", 17)
...
```

That would be easy so far by simply using a `Dictionary<string, double[]>` or `Dictionary<string, List<double>>`.

**Now this MUST be thread safe and it should have good performance. But simple data access is more important than perfomance.**

Please note that the `double[] Get(...)` returns a copy of the internal data, because returning a reference causes trouble in multithreading scenarios. Typically there would be one writer and 1-3 readers.

I tried several things like the `Dictionary<string, double[]>` and `double[]` vs. `List<double>`.

What is the best way for this? Are there other data containers/structures for that using C# 2.0?

---

EDIT:

This class should act as as data container filled by one writer thread that reads all data from a hardware. While the application is running, the UI thread reads that data simply for drawing a diagram.

A second scenario is the writer thread as before, but the UI thread is replaced by a thread that performs calculations on that data and store the results in a second data instance, which is then displayed by the UI.

Comment: What do you mean by "thread safe"?  We don't have any context on how this object is being used.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to do with a multidimensional array. This may be better in performance.

```
object[] table = new object[2];
table[0] = new string[x]; // Tags
table[0][0] = "tag";  // Example for a tag, you may iterate it

object[] doubles = new object[x];
doubles[0] = new double[y]; // Example for a column, you may iterate it

table[3] = doubles; // Doubles table
```

With this way you will have two arrays inside another array.

Note x = number of columns and y = number of rows.

Comment: The problem is that i have to access the columns with the tag string. The array has to be searched for the tag, so the dictionary was my approach (finding a index is nearly O(1)). I don't like it much, but finding a better solution is my question.